# JSoup getting several values using a loop

Tags: android, jsoup

I am using JSoup to try to get several values of a website which has "luckely" only 1 TBody tag and is build up like this:

```
<tbody>
 <tr>
   <td>2015</td>
   <td>November</td>
   <td class="no-border-left"></td>
   <td class="no-border-left">&euro; 15,90</td>
   <td>
   <a href="/Invoice/Download?invoiceNo=2632992" target="_blank"><img alt="" src="/Content/Images/pdf_icon.png" /></a>                                </td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>2015</td>
   <td>Oktober</td>
   <td class="no-border-left"></td>
   <td class="no-border-left">&euro; 16,20</td>
   <td>
   <a href="/Invoice/Download?invoiceNo=2445473" target="_blank"><img alt="" src="/Content/Images/pdf_icon.png" /></a> 
   </td>   
 </tr>
       ....
</tbody>
```

I need to get all the *year (2015), month (November), amount (€ 15,90)* and *link (a href=)* **values** through a loop as they are added to a listview.

I already got some code but somehow I am stuck at getting the amount value.
I would also like to use the "link" values later on to download some more stuff.

Could someone have a look and pls guide me a little?
Thank you.

> ```
> ....   
>  Elements Tbody = doc.select("TBODY");
>    for (Element p : Tbody) {
>
>    Iterator<Element> postIt = p.select("td").iterator();
>       String YeaR = postIt.next().text();
>       String MontH = postIt.next().text();
>
>       postIt.next();
>       postIt.next();
>
>         Element amount = doc.select("td.no-border-left").first();
>           String amounT = amount.text();
>
>          Element hrefs = doc.select("a[href]").first();
>            String linK = hrefs.text();
>    }
>   ....
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I managed to solve this.
Should anyone have the same problem, here is the working code:

```
try {
     CharSequence cs1 = "€";

     is = getActivity().getAssets().open("test.htm");
     Document doc = Jsoup.parse(is, "UTF-8", "http://example.com/");
     Elements rows = doc.select("tr");

        for (int i = 1; i < rows.size(); i++) {

         Element row = rows.get(i);
         Elements cols = row.select("td");
         Elements links = row.getElementsByTag("a");

         String YeaR = cols.get(0).text();
         //Log.e("JSOUP: ", YeaR);
         String MontH = cols.get(1).text();
         //Log.e("JSOUP: ", MontH);

            for (Element tes : cols)
                 if (tes.text().contains(cs1)) {
                     String amounT = tes.text();
                     //Log.e("JSOUP: ", amounT);
                 }
                    for (Element link : links) {
                        String url = link.attr("href");
                        //Log.e("JSOUP: ", url);
                    }
            }

            if (is != null)
                is.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

It gives the output:

```
 E/JSOUP:: 2015
 E/JSOUP:: November
 E/JSOUP:: € 15,90
 E/JSOUP:: /Invoice/Download?invoiceNo=2632992
 E/JSOUP:: 2015
 E/JSOUP:: Oktober
 E/JSOUP:: € 16,20
 E/JSOUP:: /Invoice/Download?invoiceNo=2445473
```

Answer (score 0):

Bit late to answer now, but I would do it like this:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(myHtml);

Elements tableRows = doc.select("tbody > tr"); //get all the tr elements in the table

for (Element tableRow : tableRows) { //iterate over all the table rows (tr elements)
    String year = tableRow.child(0).text() //get the first td in the row, with the year, and get the text.
    String month = tableRow.child(1).text();
    String price = tableRow.child(3).text()
    String link = tableRow.children().select("a").first().attr("href"); //get the link (a), and then get the href attribute. You can also use abs:href to get an absolute url
}
```

Comment: thx for the addition.
Yours is less code indeed but it does not take all the values for year, month, price. It does take all links though. 
Mine is a little more code but it does the job as it was intended.

Comment: @Simon, Indeed, I did not try it thoroughly but good you got a solution working anyway.